# Data not inserting into mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to insert images and autoincrement variable into mongodb but the data are not getting inserted.My code is

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var multer = require('multer');
var app=express();
var autoIncrement = require("mongoose-auto-increment");
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var connection=mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/db');
autoIncrement.initialize(connection);
var schema1 = new Schema(
{ img:{ data: Buffer, contentType: String },
   chieldId:{type:Number,autoincrement:true}
}
);
schema1.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin,{model:'carousel2',field:'chieldId'});
var Item = mongoose.model('carousel2',schema1);
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}).array('photo'));
app.post('/upload',function(req,res){
var len=req.files.length;
function repeater(i){
    if(i<len){
        var newItem = new Item();
        newItem.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.files[i].path);
        newItem.img.contentType = 'image/jpg';
        newItem.save();
        // console.log(chieldId);
        repeater(i+1);

    }
}
repeater(0);
res.send('Successfully uploaded!');
});
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
var form = '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><br><input multiple="multiple"  name="photo" type="file" /><br><br><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></form>';


res.end(form);
});
app.listen(8080);
```

When i run this code there is no error and am getting the message successfully uploaded but when i open the mongo shell and try to view the data inserted it does not return any value.Am a newbie to this any help be appreciated

Comment: This is a Mongoose question more than anything else - I suggest you tag the question as such.

Comment: @Ramya did u get the `req.files[i].path` correctly inside your repeater function.

Comment: ya i used the same code for inserting data into another model(without the autoincrement part)and is working perfectly fine but am gettingthis problme only in this code @Subburaj